# Mass storage mode for an SD card connected to a MSP430G2553 chip?

Tags: usb, uart, msp430, sd, ftdi

Right now I have a program that stores values obtained from the on chip ADC to a SD card.  The card is connected like the diagram shown in this PDF:

- [Interfacing the MSP430 With MMC/SD Flash Memory Cards](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa281b/slaa281b.pdf)

I am planning to connect a UART-to-USB chip (FTDI or MAXIM's) so I can send data to a PC as well.

So the question is, is it possible for the PC to read the SD card through the microcontroller similar to the way that MP3 players act like mass storage devices when they are connected to PC?

Here's a diagram for clarity:

[SD card] <--> [MSP430G2553] <--> [FTDI chip] <--> [PC]

Thanks.

Comment: The FAT filesystem libraries I have seen all require somewhat over 512 bytes (the disk sector size) of RAM.  The msp430g2553 has exactly 512 bytes of RAM.  Have you found a filesystem library that lets you use less RAM?

Comment: The file system we're using is the petitFAT and it seems to work on the 2553

Comment: Thank you.  That is the first I've seen of that project (I've used the bigger FatFS before).

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad I was able to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a USB-Serial adaptor. That is a USB communications device class (CDC), not the USB Mass Storage Device class.

Comment: Oh, so do you mean I can get mass storage mode to work if I got a MSC adapter instead of the CDC adapter?

Comment: @user2218339 A MSC adaptor, in this case, is called a SD Card Reader...

Comment: Oh... I was hoping that I can connect to the SD card through the msp430 without having to unplug it and plug it in a standalone card reader.

Comment: @user2218339 what you can do is use a multiplexer (mux). Connect the sd card to the common side, then the selectable side A would go to msp430, while the selectable side b would go to a sd card reader. Then you can use a switch (or the msp430) to switch inbetween the two.